# Unaligned exception behaviour mips

Tags: exception, mips

Say I have this instruction in MIPS

```
lw $t0, 21($s0)
```

`$s0` contains the decimal `2022` (not a multiple of four)

Here, The exception will arise just on looking at the address at `$s0` or after the computation of the address `21+$s0` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception will be caused by trying to load from address 21($s0), or 2022+21 = 2043 decimal. `EPC` will contain the address of the load instruction when the exception happened, and the `BadVaddr` register should contain decimal 2043.